# Online translation service for (open source) Apps

Tags: android, open-source, translation, community-translations

my own Android-apps typically come in English and my native language but I want to provide some more translations to the public.

I remember, some time ago I found an App, which used an online translation service for this job: there they uploaded their existing XML files with the texts and other users could create new ones for other languages online. All was done in easy to use online forms so that the translators would not have to deal with XML and its format rules. Later the maintainer of the App could download the ready-to-use new translations and integrate them into the App.

This was a free service for open source Apps and was exactly what I'm looking for.

Unfortunately I have no idea which service this was/where to find it and Google gives me only paid services.

So: any idea where I could do that in a similar way, means where volunteers are able to translate my open source App online?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can register your application on:

- https://translatewiki.net/
- http://transifex.com/

if it is an open source. I'm not sure about registration details for Transifex, I think you need to pay a bit, but you can check on Translatewiki for [more details](https://translatewiki.net/wiki/Translating:New_project).